# Need border around icon using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working with borders here I want to add the border to the icon as shown in the image. so far I did this can anyone suggest me point me in the right direction

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 182px;
  background: aliceblue;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  width: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

i.fa {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is the number of icons flexible, or is it always 7 icons forever? Is the area resizable, or could it be that the icons may take up e.g. 2 or 4 rows at some point?

Comment: @ Peter B no it is flexible the number of icons will change not static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea using pseudo element and one border. You add `border-right` to only the first and second element of each row and for each first element starting from the second row you add a whole line on the top that will cover the row.

```css
.list {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin:5px;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 182px;
  background: aliceblue;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  width: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative; /*Don't forget this*/
}
/*The magic starts here */
li:not(:nth-child(3n + 3)) {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
li:nth-child(3n + 4):before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:120px;
  height:1px;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/**/
i.fa {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Making use of solid colour and negative margins you can achieve that easily. please have a look at the below working snippet, hope it help :)

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 182px;
  background: aliceblue;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  width: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: -1px -1px 0 0;
}

i.fa {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

above answer was my personal opinion to have a better ui design, in order to achieve the result as per the screenshot you can do that by using `table` tag and few lines of css as shown in the below code snippet. it has it's own catch of having rows, which you need to control :)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: hidden;
}
table td {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: inset;
  border-color:#ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks but what about the first-child border-left i don't want

Comment: Then target the first `li` with the nth-child selector - see my answer below. Otherwise this is a correct solution to me.

Comment: @Girisha C can you please update your answer using the nth-child selector.

Comment: I see 7 fully boxed icons (borders on all sides), both in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Husna just copy paste the solution, and add `li:nth-child(1) { border-left-style: none; }`

Comment: @Husna, @Peter B - please have a look at the above second answer using `table` it has it's own catch of having rows, which needs to be controlled :(

Answer (score 1):

I would either use `.nth-child` pseudo-class of the icons to put specific borders on each one, or better yet (in my opinion) put a class on each one based on the borders it needs (`.border-right`, `.border-bottom` etc.). This makes your html a little more descriptive in terms of indicating what the class should do to the element.

The advantage of the `.nth-child` method is you can rearrange the elements without changing their classes and still achieve the same results. You will have to write a little more css but it's pretty straightforward stuff so that's not a real concern.

Answer (score 1):

**Please try following code. also you can add more icon looking good design**

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 182px;
  background: aliceblue;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}
li {
  width: 33.33%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  max-width: 33.33%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
li:nth-child(3n-5) {
  border-left: none;
}
li:nth-child(n+2) {
  border-right: none;
}
i.fa {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what kind of explanation is this *Please try following code i am working on your issue till when you post issue* ?

Answer (score 1):

If and only if the number of icon in a single row(3) is fixed.

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 182px;
  background: aliceblue;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  width: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  border-right: 0;
}

i.fa {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way you are doing this, I think the easiest solution for you would be to target specifically the 5th and 6th child elements. You can do this with the `nth-child(n)` css selector - so `li:nth-child(5)` to target the G+ icon box for example, and then just add the style for a bottom border. More information: https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: yeah but if the icons are less or more if they have more than 3 rows?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work too well if you don't know the amount of rows. But for hardcoding the amount of icons as you have in the example, this should work.